# ExpandableListView getChildrenCount not called after data changed, leading to IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, expandablelistview, indexoutofboundsexception, notifydatasetchanged

In my `Activity`, I change the underlying data `HashMap` for my `ExpandableListView`, and then call

```
((BaseAdapter) myExpandableListView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

However, the app crashes after calling this, raising an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

I double-checked that I access the same and right data everywhere in the adapter, but could not find any mistakes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After a bit of debugging, I finally found out that, strangely enough, `getChildrenCount` is never called after I called `notifyDataSetChanged`. Thus, the Adapter is still expecting to get the same number of children as there were before the update.
As I removed some children, that's a wrong assumption, and leads to the `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

After a bit of playing around, I discovered that for `ExpandableListViews`, the Adapter has to be accessed via `getExpandableListAdapter()`, not via getAdapter().
After changing my code to

```
((BaseExpandableListAdapter) myExpandableListView.getExpandableListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Everything works fine now.

I hope this helps any fellow developers. I spent a few hours finding and fixing this, and hardly found any information about it on the web and StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

```kotlin
listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
               
val groupPosition = 0
expandableListView.expandGroup(groupPosition, true)
```

I solved my problem by add the method `expandableListView.expandGroup()` after called `notifyDataSetChanged()`.